# Directory services for my home network

Tags: windows-7

I'm running Windows 7 Ultimate 64 as a combination HTPC/utility "server". I have several other computers on my network and would love to be able to have LDAP services so that I can have just one set of accounts across all my computers.

I've read a very small amount about [AD-LDS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Directory#ADAM.2FAD_LDS) (formerly called ADAM), and it seems like it would allow me to do so without running a server OS in a VM, but I can't seem to find where to download and/or install it. It isn't listed in the list of Windows features/components, and Googling doesn't seem to get me anywhere, at least for Windows 7.

Is AD-LDS really what I want, and if so, is it possible to get it running on Windows 7, or will I need to run a server OS in a VM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[AD-LDS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770639(WS.10).aspx) is a server role available on Windows Server 2008 and Windows Server 2008 R2. It is also extremely hard to work with as an end user as it is focussed at developers and orginisations that run full scale domains.

You have 2 options available. You can either look at [OpenLDAP](http://www.openldap.org/) which is open source and installed on Linux, or alternatively loading a Windows Server into a VM. I do the latter and it makes life easier.

I would only tackle the AD-LDS route if I was intent on learning the inner workings of AD and LDAP.